# Pronoun not matching noun

Tags: nouns, pronouns

> Users are asked to read the document before you come to the venue.

This sentence is grammatically incorrect because "Users" doesn't match "you". Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. The sentence jumps from the formal, impersonal address to direct address.

Comment: 'Users: you are asked to read the document before you come to the venue.' is unarguably correct, but more in-your-face. As the meaning is clear, I'd say the softer version, while extragrammatical (pushing it) in the intended sense (a zeugma), is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

It's a grammatically valid sentence, and it could conceivably be correct if "you" and "users" refer to different people.

Consider a scenario where a company is delivering an IT system to another, and they are sending a representative to brief the users on its features. The users have been given a document to read that addresses some of the anticipated questions, and the customer is informing the provider that the users have been asked to read this document.

In almost all other scenarios, though, the sentence will not be what the author intended.